# Python3 : How two objects from same class are different?

Tags: python, oop

I am looking at simple python code like below

```
class Robot:
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Robot()
    y = Robot()
    y2 = y
    print(y == y2)
    print(y == x)
```

and output is

```
True
False
```

That's the advantage of OOP concept, I understand. But what makes it different like when two different objects are reference to same class they almost have same properties but something is different and I want to know that property which is different.

EDIT: I think this question is not duplicate to given question below. I want to see each object more deeply something like skeleton structure. They have different ID's I can understand that because object ID concept in python is something similar to [variable ID's concept](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_variables.php) , only ID's assigning concept.

Thank you.

Comment: because those are 2 instances for x and y. y2 and y share the same reference.

Comment: `print id(x), id(y), id(x) != id(y)`

Comment: @mu無 Can I take this concept it a little deeper ? Please excuse me if its a silly question but I want to ask. Is there any way I can see what properties were adopted to reference objects ?

Comment: @Raja I don't understand how object identity is related to any "skeleton structure". Actually in python an object's structure can change but it still is the same object.

Comment: @Goyo oh please excuse me for my reply. I am saying I dont want to differ two objects by their ID's and I want to differ two objects by their other properties. is it possible ? I dont know what are the other properties and I would like to know if they are exist. Thank you.

Comment: @Raja No, only the `id` is guaranteed to be different. I added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called *identity* and you can get (a numeric representation of) it by using the function [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

```
print(id(x))
print(id(y))
print(id(y2))

163193456
163193584
163193584
```

The only thing which is necessarily different in two objects is the identity (the result of calling `id` on them, if you want to be pragmatic). Everything else can be the same.